# Knockout arrayForEach undefined property

Tags: javascript, function, knockout.js

I'm having trouble trying to get a number from each item in a knockout observable array and add the numbers together and assign it to another computed variable. Here's what I have right now...

```
Semesters: ko.observableArray([
    {
        semesterName: "Fall",
        semesterCode: "300",
        PlannedCourses: ko.observableArray([]),
        totalCredits: ko.computed(function(){
            var total = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.PlannedCourses, function (course) {
                total += course.MinHours();
            });

            return total;
        }),
    },
    ...
```

What I'm trying to do is, in the totalCredits variable, I'm trying to iterate through the PlannedCourses array and get the MinHours variable for each item and add them together in the total variable. Then I return it to the totalCredits item in the Semesters array. The issue I'm having is getting the PlannedCourses variable in the ko.utils.arrayForEach part. I'm getting an undefined on it and I'm not sure why. I think it's a simple syntax error but I can't see what's wrong.

The PlannedCourses observable array is a dynamic object that is getting the list of PlannedCourses properly. It's defined in the context of itself but I'm not passing it to the totalCredits computed function properly.

I hope this is clear enough. Thank you for your help!

Note: All the rest of the code is working as intended. The only part that isn't working is the totalCredits computed function. I'm not sure if anything within the ko.utils.arrayForEach is working as I haven't been able to get that far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need to change the way you populate your `Semesters` observable array to use a constructor function in order to get a reference to the correct scope for `this`:

```
function semester(name, code) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Code = code;
    this.PlannedCourses = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.totalCredits = ko.computed(function(){
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.PlannedCourses(), function (course) {
            //Note the change to "this.PlannedCourses()" above to get the underlying array
            total += course.MinHours();
        });

        return total;
    }, this); //now we can pass "this" as the context for the computed
}
```

See how we can now pass in an object to the second argument for `ko.computed` to use as the context for `this` in the inner function.  For more information, see the knockout docs: [Managing 'this'](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing-this).

You then create new instances of `semester` when populating your array:

```
Semesters: ko.observableArray([
    new semester("Fall", "300"),
    new semester(...)
]);
```

This approach also means you have a consistent way of creating your `semester` objects (the computed is only defined once for one thing), rather than possibly incorporating typos etc in any repetition you may originally have had.

Comment: This is probably the best approach. I'm going to have to do a lot of restructuring but there's no doubt I should be doing this. I appreciate it. i'm trying to incorporate a couple of different viewModel methods and it's making things complicated. Right now "Semesters" is an item that's part of yet another array "Years" that has "academicWork" and "Semesters" that's structured much the same way of "Semesters". If I rework both lists to the way you have specified, this should work. It's going to take some time, though. I'll get back to you soon if this worked. Thanks again!

Comment: If you're creating multiple objects with the same properties/functions etc, this would be the usual approach

Answer (score 0):

The scope (this) isn't what you think it is.

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

try adding your context, like the following:

```
Semesters: ko.observableArray([
{
    semesterName: "Fall",
    semesterCode: "300",
    PlannedCourses: ko.observableArray([]),
    totalCredits: ko.computed(function(){
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.PlannedCourses, function (course) {
            total += course.MinHours();
        });

        return total;
    }, this), // new context passed in here
},
...
```

Doing this passes in the context of the array item itself into your computed function.

Edit:
you may need to access the Semesters object inside you loop, and add some way to reference the current item:

```
Semesters: ko.observableArray([
{
    semesterName: "Fall",
    semesterCode: "300",
    PlannedCourses: ko.observableArray([]),
    totalCredits: ko.computed(function(){
        var total = 0;
        for( var i = 0, len = Semesters().length; i < len; i++ ) {
            // check current array item, possibly add an id?
            if( Semesters()[i].semesterName === "Fall" &&
                Semesters()[i].semesterCode === "300" ) {

                ko.utils.arrayForEach(Semesters()[i].PlannedCourses, function (course) {
                   total += course.MinHours();
                });
                break; // done searching
            }
        }

        return total;
    })
},
```

Comment: With the way the object is being constructed, `this` won't even be the right thing on the outer scope either.

Comment: @JamesThorpe My thoughts exactly

Comment: It appears @JomesThorpe is right. I'm still getting undefined for PlannedCourses. I'm 100% sure it's on PlannedCourses, as well. When commenting out the computed function for totalCredits, the undefined error goes away. In the console, when I look at:
da.vm.Years()[0].Semesters()[0].PlannedCourses()
I'm getting a list of objects in the PlannedCourses array as intended. So the list is populating...

Comment: @JoshSalazar, you need a lookup based of the root Semester array, I think. Check my edit

Comment: @dperry. I see where you're going with this. Let me give it a shot before I try restructuring everything. I'll get back to you soon. Thank you!

Comment: @JoshSalazar While this may work, I _really_ recommend you don't take this approach in the long term.  Work with JavaScript and how it's scoping works.

Comment: @JamesThorpe , you're right. I do need to make the changes you have suggested. That structure is how we're currently doing things in all other parts of the application. For the sake of learning, practicing and understanding, I'm going to try dperry's solution to see if works, make sense of it, then restructure it all as per your suggestion. Luckily I'm not on a deadline with this. :) Thank you both very much.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I missed how you were defining a Semester object, and you are absolutely right. JoshSalazar: Define your objects and put the knockout functionality in there just like he did it.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned your `this` is not what you think it is. In your case the context should be passed to the computed as follows:

```
totalCredits: ko.computed(function() {
    // Computation goes here..
}, this)
```

Another approach could be to store the correct `this` to some local variable during the object creation (ex. `var self = this;` and then use `self` instead of `this`).

However, `ko.utils.arrayForEach` doesn't work with observable arrays but works on pure JavaScript arrays, so you should unwrap the observable array to access the elements of the underlying array:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.PlannedCourses(), function(course) { 
    // ...
});

// Or

ko.utils.arrayForEach(ko.unwrap(this.PlannedCourses), function(course) { 
    // ... 
});
```

Comment: "However, ko.utils.arrayForEach doesn't work with observable arrays but works on pure JavaScript arrays"

I wasn't aware of that. Thank you.

I've edited my code to use the ko.unwrap and have assigned self to this. I'm still getting undefined for PlannedCourses, though. Let me take another look and see if I can figure out what's going on outside the scope of my error...